# Session cookie lost in proxyPass with apache server

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache, oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy

I have a configured reverse proxy in apache server to authenticate user throughs oauth2.

When the proxy path is different than the one in the server, the **session** cookie is lost and i get **authorization_request_not_found** error.

The following configuration is working fine while **/backend** in both:

```
ProxyPass "/backend" "http://localhost:8085/backend"
ProxyPassReverse "/backend" "http://localhost:8085/backend"
```

When i configure a different path i can't see the session Cookie so the authentication fail:

```
ProxyPass "/service" "http://localhost:8085/backend"
ProxyPassReverse "/service" "http://localhost:8085/backend"
```

In this case **/service** is different than **/backend**

Can you please help me through the required config to pass the cookie to the backend to keep the functionality as expected.

Thank you

Comment: Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/919969/apache-reverse-proxy-proxypassreversecookiedomain-not-seeming-to-work

Comment: Thank you @Nic3500, my reverse proxy is handling /auth/login and forward call to /backend/oauth2/code/company which make it different than just the root /. I can't really configure it correctly even with that answer.